# Linq to SQL: Get top 10 most ordered products

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, select

I'm wanting to grab the 10 most ordered products. My tables look similar to this:

**Product**
`ProductID | ProductName`

**OrderedProduct**
`ProductID | OrderID`

**Order**
`OrderID | DateOrdered`

At the moment I've got the following:

```
return (from product in db.Products
        from orderedProduct in db.OrderedProducts
        where orderedProduct.ProductID == product.ProductID
        select product).OrderByDescending(???).Distinct().Take(10);
```

I've noted in the above query where I'm uncertain of what to put. How do I orderby the number of products that appear in the ordered products table?

Comment: You may find this question useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322675/linq-keyword-search-with-orderby-relevance-based-on-count-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
return (from product in db.Products
        from orderedProduct in db.OrderedProducts
        where orderedProduct.ProductID == product.ProductID
        group orderedProduct by product into productGroups
        select new 
        {
              product = productGroups.Key, 
              numberOfOrders = productGroups.Count() 
        }
        ).OrderByDescending(x => x.numberOfOrders).Distinct().Take(10);
```

It will give you 10 items, each item contains product object, and numberOfOrders integer.

**Edit**:

Since this will be as a return value for a method, and since C# doesn't allow returning an anonymous type (yet .. this feature is in C# 4.0), you convert the anonymous type into a class.

Create a class of the type you want to return

```
public class ProductOrders
{
    public ProductOrders() {
    }

    public Product product { get; set; }
    public int numberOfOrders { get; set; }
}
```

and Use this query to return objects of that class

```
 return (from product in db.Products
        from orderedProduct in db.OrderedProducts
        where orderedProduct.ProductID == product.ProductID
        group orderedProduct by product into productGroups
        select new ProductOrders
        {
              product = productGroups.Key, 
              numberOfOrders = productGroups.Count() 
        }
        ).OrderByDescending(x => x.numberOfOrders).Distinct().Take(10);
```

The return value now is of type **`IEnumerable<ProductOrders>`**.

Comment: How do I go about extracting the product from this object?

Comment: assuming the return value is stored in x, use `x.product.ProductID` and `x.product.ProductName`

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure what datatype I should use to store the result from the query above. Do I make my own?